# Robot framework Browser library with BrowserStack

Tags: browser, robotframework, playwright, browserstack

Is it possible to use [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) when using [Browser](https://robotframework-browser.org/) library in [RobotFramework](https://robotframework.org/)

There is an article on how to do it with SeleniumLibrary ( https://medium.com/detesters/integrating-robot-framework-with-browserstock-bddf5b0e0c14 )

and also an article on how to do it with Playwright directly ([see this page](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/playwright) )

But can it be done with Browser library, and if yes, how is that done?

Comment: Please checkout BrowserStack with Robot Selenium library sample project, here: https://github.com/BrowserStackCE/browserstack-examples-robot

Answer (score 1):

With the following **init**.robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Force Tags       test
Documentation    Test Suite
Suite Setup      Setup Browserstack
Resource         ../Variables/variables.robot
Library          Browser

*** Variables ***
&{desiredCapabilities}      os=Windows
...                         os_version=10
...                         browser=chrome
...                         name=TestInit
...                         browserstack.username=${BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME}
...                         browserstack.accessKey=${BROWSERSTACK_ACCESSKEY}
...                         client.playwrightVersion=1.17.2

*** Keywords ***
Setup Browserstack
    ${BSENCODEDCAPS}            Evaluate    urllib.parse.quote( json.dumps(${desiredCapabilities}) )
    Connect To Browser          wss://cdp.browserstack.com/playwright?caps=${BSENCODEDCAPS}
```

It took some time, but with the help of a great colleague I was able to get this.